# Using Private PGP key as login credential?

Tags: security, gpg, pgp

This is NOT for the likes of remote SSH, but is somewhat similar for local physical use with a USB key device. Could I somehow setup a customized personalized login system that uses my own Private PGP Key to login and unlock my user profile directory if it were encrypted at install?

I was just wondering how possible that was that I have my own personally signed private PGP key saved on my own lock and keep USB storage device that nobody knows about, and whenever inserted to the computer's USB port to automatically read and unlock my user profile upon detecting the correct private PGP key to login and unlock my user profile directory with, therefore not requiring to need to type your password in everytime.

things that would need to be considered is the computer needs to have the correct UDEV rules along with the ID of the USB device you have your private PGP key onto read upon inserting.

Would there be any potential security risks to this? *Besides losing your USB device with your private PGP key, or falls into the wrong hands of course.*

Comment: Have you looked into anything like YubiKey?

Comment: I've heard about those but as I believe you need to buy a special keychain for that. I would prefer to use something I actually have on hand.

Comment: https://web.archive.org/web/20140105170539/http://pamusb.org/ was something similar. It was packaged for Debian at least (https://tracker.debian.org/pkg/libpam-usb) but was removed as unmaintained and requiring udisks1. But it's still in Jessie. Edit: seems to have moved to here: https://github.com/aluzzardi/pam_usb BTW: You really want a Smart Card of some sort.

Comment: @user94959 I am owner of several Yubikeys. There is no need to buy a special keychain. Yubikeys behave like a smartcard and therefore can import existing keys. If you want to create a new key, just do it on a secure machine and import signing, authentication and  encryption keys into the Yubikey and store the master key on a secure place.